# How can I do a git pull in Maven?

Tags: git, maven, pom.xml, maven-scm

I'm new to both maven and git and wanted to get some help in setting a project.

Is there a way to define a goal in the pom to push/pull from git during linked to a maven phase? For example, can I pull from git during the maven install phase?

If yes, how can that be accomplished? I would appreciate any code examples.

Comment: Why would you like to push or pull during a build? Sounds like a really bad idea.

Comment: It's not really a build. The project contains automated tests. And the way our test framework is setup we need to pull the latest framework code to run the tests from time to time.

Comment: Assuming the pull will fast-forward (no merge resolution needed), isn't just running "git pull repoName" then "mvn arguments" simple enough? If it may not fast forward, how should maven handle it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Good idea or not, here's how you could do a checkout (<del>pull</del> clone from Github) using Maven. Have your pom.xml look like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>br.com.javamagazine</groupId>
<artifactId>engesoft</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>engesoft Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:git://github.com/vitorsouza/EngeSoft.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:https://vitorsouza@github.com/vitorsouza/EngeSoft.git</developerConnection>
    <url>https://github.com/vitorsouza/EngeSoft</url>
</scm>
</project>
```

Then use `mvn scm:checkout`. When I ran this, it pulled the code to folder `target/engesoft`. There's probably a way to configure it to place it somewhere else. Check out the following pages:

- [Maven SCM Plug-in](http://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/index.html)
- [Git implementation for the SCM Plug-in](http://maven.apache.org/scm/git.html)

Comment: Where do you specify the git password?

Comment: I use SSH keys instead of password. See https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys

Answer (score 4):

Instead of doing this during the Maven build, use a CI server like [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/). It will do the `git pull` before running maven, so the build tool can concentrate on it's main purpose: Building source code.

This also makes it more simple for you to develop since pull's will only happen when you want them. If you pull all the time, another developer can change something and you will get errors that you don't expect.

Answer (score 2):

The **scm:checkout goal** Vitor is referring to is a clone, not a pull (huge difference in Git).

I had to use the exec goal to do what you're describing. I also didn't want to do an entire clone each time there was a build. Instead, I use **git reset --hard** and then **pull -f origin Release:Release** (via exec).

If I find a better way (and there HAS to be one) I'll post it here.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm still a git newbie.