# How can I set a compile time variable in a SWF with the same ID as a Maven artifact?

Tags: actionscript-3, git, maven

I would like to set a variable in my swf at compile time that reads the current commit/branch from git and also edits the pom.xml with that name as the artifact id.
I want to do this so that I can query a swf and retreive which version of the maven build it is.

Is this possible, and which plugins would I use to do this?

I have done this sort of thing [using ANT in the past](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_21.html), but I need to be able to do it using Maven instead.
My searches on the internet have mostly revealed ways to do this in Java but not in Actionscript.

Comment: I see I need to wait for the answer to this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13583953/deriving-maven-artifact-version-from-git-branch
How can I "watch" it?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the [flexmojo's](http://flexmojos.sonatype.org/) plugin. Have a look at the flexmojo's [definesDeclaration](http://repository.sonatype.org/content/sites/flexmojos-site/3.8/compile-swc-mojo.html#definesDeclaration) parameter. This will allow you to pass in values for the compiler variables you define in your Actionscript project with the `-define` option (per the Adobe article you've linked to).

Then it's just a matter of setting that value to the artifact ID, date/time, or whatever.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good starting point, but how do I programatically pull it from git?

Comment: Maybe something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359332/how-can-i-do-a-git-pull-in-maven) will help.

Comment: Sorry, you misunderstood me.  I mean how do I get the branch name into the version of the pom.xml.  That is, I want to change the value in the pom before running through the build. (I'll then set that name as the compile time var in the swf)