# Push to github rejected with maven-release-plugin

Tags: java, git, maven, github, maven-release-plugin

I've spent hours trying to release a project to github with Maven. This is usually not a problem but for some reason it is for this project and I don't understand why. I'm using Maven 3.8.5 with Java 1.8.0_312 and git 2.36.1. Here's the pom.xml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>se.company.myproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>myproject-base</name>
    <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.36</slf4j.version>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>module1</module>
        <module>module2</module>
        <module>module3</module>
    </modules>

    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:ssh://git@github.com/mycompany/myproject.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://git@github.com/mycompany/myproject.git</developerConnection>
        <url>https://github.com/mycompany/myproject.git</url>
        <tag>4.0.0</tag>
    </scm>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>se.company.myproject</groupId>
                <artifactId>some-internal-dependency</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Test dependencies -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
                <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
                <version>3.9.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.13.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <tagNameFormat>@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
                    <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>company-releases</id>
            <name>Internal Releases</name>
            <url>https://company.se/company-maven-releases/</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>company-snapshots</id>
            <name>Internal Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://company.se/company-maven-snapshots/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>company-releases</id>
            <url>https://company.se/company-maven-releases/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

When I run `maven release:prepare` I get this:

```
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ myproject-module3 ---
[INFO] [INFO] Building jar: /Users/me/code/module3/target/myproject-module3-4.0.0.jar
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Reactor Summary for myproject-base 4.0.0:
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] myproject-base ..................................... SUCCESS [  0.059 s]
[INFO] [INFO] module1............................................. SUCCESS [  1.097 s]
[INFO] [INFO] module2 ............................................ SUCCESS [  0.603 s]
[INFO] [INFO] module3 ............................................ SUCCESS [  0.046 s]
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Total time:  1.878 s
[INFO] [INFO] Finished at: 2022-05-20T14:29:16+02:00
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [prepare] 11/17 scm-commit-release
[INFO] Checking in modified POMs...
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd '/Users/me/code/myproject' && 'git' 'add' '--' 'pom.xml' 'module1/pom.xml' 'module2/pom.xml' 'module3/pom.xml'
[INFO] Working directory: /Users/me/code/myproject
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd '/Users/me/code/myproject' && 'git' 'rev-parse' '--show-prefix'
[INFO] Working directory: /Users/me/code/myproject
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd '/Users/me/code/myproject' && 'git' 'status' '--porcelain' '.'
[INFO] Working directory: /Users/me/code/myproject
[WARNING] Ignoring unrecognized line: ?? module1/pom.xml.releaseBackup
[WARNING] Ignoring unrecognized line: ?? module2/pom.xml.releaseBackup
[WARNING] Ignoring unrecognized line: ?? pom.xml.releaseBackup
[WARNING] Ignoring unrecognized line: ?? release.properties
[WARNING] Ignoring unrecognized line: ?? module3/pom.xml.releaseBackup
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd '/Users/me/code/myproject' && 'git' 'commit' '--verbose' '-F' '/var/folders/xb/pl4xth9n5qbgksbyy2fy5lm80000gn/T/maven-scm-1737591658.commit'
[INFO] Working directory: /Users/me/code/myproject
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd '/Users/me/code/myproject' && 'git' 'symbolic-ref' 'HEAD'
[INFO] Working directory: /Users/me/code/myproject
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd '/Users/me/code/myproject' && 'git' 'push' 'ssh:********@github.com/company/myproject.git' 'refs/heads/main:refs/heads/main'
[INFO] Working directory: /Users/me/code/myproject
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for myproject-base 3.0.1-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO] 
[INFO] myproject-base ........................................ FAILURE [  8.100 s]
[INFO] module1 ............................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] module2 ............................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] module3 ............................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  8.207 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-05-20T14:29:18+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:3.0.0-M5:prepare (default-cli) on project myproject: Unable to commit files
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-push command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] To ssh://github.com/company/myproject.git
[ERROR]  ! [rejected]        main -> main (non-fast-forward)
[ERROR] error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://github.com/company/myproject.git'
[ERROR] hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
[ERROR] hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
[ERROR] hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
[ERROR] hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I can push (and pull) just fine from the command line by using the `git` command. I've tried different versions of the `maven-release-plugin` to no avail. I've even deleted the entire GitHub repository and pushed it again from my local machine but still, I get the same error. What could be causing this?

Comment: Do you mean github on internet or corporate GitHub?

Comment: I mean github.com

Comment: What does the `git status` command return in terminal?

Comment: The `main -> main (non-fast-forward)` error is pretty basic and well-covered in existing SO questions; the real question seems to be why maven is causing the situation (which isn't really a *Git* question, nor java nor github).

Comment: @Boris It says that everything is up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

A `mvn -X` prepare should show you which commit is checked out from your `git:ssh://git@github.com/mycompany/myproject.git`

Compare it with the latest commit on GitHub to understand the difference.

Trying to use an `exec` goal to do a [`git pull` before `mvn release`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10147826/6309) is possible, but it is better to identify first why there is a remote commit that you do not have locally.